# Creating a non-generic entity derived from a generic abstract class in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, inheritance, entity-framework-6

*I've already seen [Generics and inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526050/generics-and-inheritance-in-c-sharp) but I'm not sure if it's exactly the same thing.*

Suppose that I have a user entity in my database:

```
public abstract class User{ ... }
```

I have some classes derived from it:

```
public class NormalUser : User { ... }
public class SuperUser : User { ... }
```

I have the appropriate `DbSet`s in my context for both derived classes (and not for `User` base class, obviously). There is no problem up to here.

Now, I want to create some other object called `Attachment`, that all users can have. But this is an abstract class. It will not be implemented solely, but I know that it will be created by some subclass of the `User`. I could directly try out a `User` property, but no, in the derived classes, I'd like to have a strongly typed user property that is mapped to `NormalUser` or `SuperUser` (or any other).

I've ended up like this:

```
public abstract class Attachment<T> where T : User
{
    ...

    public long CreatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual T Creator { get; set; }

}
```

I know that Entity Framework does not support generics, but I'm not having `Attachment` itself as an entity. Now, I've created a derived class, replacing the generic as required:

```
public class NormalUserAttachment : Attachment<NormalUser> {

   public string SomeExtraDataJustForNormalUserAttachments{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

Now, I've got a new class that is derived from `Attachment` and has it's properties with `NormalUser` as the `User` type.

However, when I try to run the app (automatic migrations enabled) I'm getting an error with `dbo.NormalUserAttachment` not existing.

Why would this be happening? I'm not directly using a generic type, I'm using a non-generic type that is derived from a generic type, but with all the generics replaced with actual types. Is it still not supported, or is it something else? I'm on Entity Framework 6.1.3, code-first.

Comment: It seems that it tries to create a table for your class NormalUserAttachment. Do you use code first or database first ?

Comment: @romain-aga I am on code-first. Of course, it's trying. It should create. But I don't why it fails doing so

Comment: Well, my guess is, you are inheritating from a generic class, and that might be the problem. Did you try without the inheritance or the generic part ? And you said, you didn't want `Attachment` as an entity. Then, how do you create your table ?

Comment: @romain-aga I don't need to create a table for the base abstract class to be able to create a table/DbSet for the derived class. entity framework handles that perfectly by creating only the table for the derived class with the inherited properties from the abstract class, as it should trivially do. we are using that pattern at many places with no problem.

Comment: So, what you are showing actually in your question, it's used everywhere in your program ? If it's the case, you should have a minor difference between your usages, and the issue might not come from your pattern. But something else. Did you have the same issue for `SuperUserAttachment` ?

Comment: hmm, your issue *should* not be supported. Since EF would have to create an FK for the navigation property, however it has not one single table it references, but two different - it would need to create two FK's for one navigation property, and I doubt this is supported.

Comment: @romain-aga I think you didn't understand the problem. I don't have problems with classes derived from abstract classes, which is what I'm using everywhere. the problem arises when that abstract class is also generic. then, my derived *non*-generic class fails too, and I don't understand why.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro if the generic base class wasn't abstract then yes, it was right. but I'm not using that class. it's just a base class. the actual class used as an entity already defines that generic parameter as a `NormalUser` which I have in the database, so any foreign key/navigation property shouldn't be an issue at all.

Comment: Well, you said `Entity Framework does not support generics`. So, to create your derived classes from your generic abstract class, first, you have to create a generic abstract class... which entity does not support. Do you have generic inheritance (for entities) in other places in your project ? If not, then you have your answer, you can't inherit from an generic class.

Comment: @romain-aga just because EF doesn't directly support generics doesn't necessarily mean that it also doesn't support non-generic classes that are only derived from abstract generics. and just because I don't have any other  samples in my project with the particular doesn't mean that it's not supported. there might be something else. I need an authoritative answer for this.

Comment: Well, if you don't have other example, make you another one to check this. If it doesn't work, that would answer to your question or at least give a big hint. If it does, we would know that it doesn't come from that.

Comment: @romain-aga I'm short on time to create a new project solely to test this. it's why I've posted on stackoverflow, as someone may know the answer. that's why Q&A communities exist.